# Hyperref: do not create target anchors for lists

Tags: hyperref

The package `hyperref` automatically creates target anchors for pages, figures, and so on. Even if a target is not referred to, it is included in the final PDF. These targets can be seen, for instance, if the bookmarks of the final PDF are edited via Adobe Acrobat.

Most of these targets have useful names, but some of these targets are neither necessary nor helpful (and kind of litter the list of targets). Is there a way to prevent the creation of these targets for special types of labels or especially for `enumerate` list environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the following variants. The `\patchcmd` will only suppress the Item-anchors, the `\AddToHook` variant will suppress all anchors created by a `\refstepcounter` inside the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\refstepcounter{\hyper@refstepcounter{Item}}{}{}{\fail}
%\AddToHook{env/enumerate/begin}{\@skiphyperreftrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item a 
\item b
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Interestingly, the `\patchcmd` variant causes an _Undefined control sequence_ (on the quick I could not figure out the reason, since I use a rather complex template), but the `\AddToHook` variant works fine!